# Download a file to a server?

Tags: shell, wget, url

After ssh to a server, I want to download  two files in https://iain.cx/src/ktmux/#download to the server. So for the first file ktmux_helper, I right click to find its link on my local computer, and run wget with the link on the server as:

```
wget https://git.iain.cx/?p=profile.git;a=blob_plain;f=opt/bin/ktmux_helper;hb=HEAD
```

But the downloaded file seems to be a html file, instead of an expected perl file. How shall I download the two files then?

Comment: The link does return an HTML page, with the script enclosed in `pre` tags. We could use an HTML parser (or regex!) to extract the contents of the `pre` tag, or manually copy out the part and SCP it to the server. Which would you prefer? (Or you could also clone the git repo).

Comment: prefer do it directly from the server. either parse html (how? there is no `pre` tag nor the script in the html file), or clone git (what is the address?). how then?

Comment: The git server address is given in https://git.iain.cx/?p=profile.git;a=summary, and now that I actually download it, it looks like it inserts a pre tag only if you're using a browser.

Comment: Thanks. How do you find out the git address?

Comment: remove the `a=blob_plain;` from the URL, this will lead you to a better web ui. From there, head to the summary page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the shell is interpreting the semicolons, which make the command line look like a wget and several variable assignment statements. You need to put the URL in quotes:

```
wget 'https://git.iain.cx/?p=profile.git;a=blob_plain;f=opt/bin/ktmux_helper;hb=HEAD'
```

Without the quotes, the shell splits the commmand line up at each semi colon, and treats it as 4 separate statements:

```
wget https://git.iain.cx/?p=profile.git
a=blob_plain
f=opt/bin/ktmux_helper
hb=HEAD
```

By luck, these are all syntactically valid, so you didn't get any shell errors or warnings. The first one is the one that gave you the HTML file since it was missing the modifier that told the server that you wanted a plain text file.

Comment: The joys of cgi parameters and the command line. The ampersand is just as bad as the semicolon except that you have multiple jobs running in the background doing nothing but assigning variables. I hate that. The one thing I would do differently is use single quotes. It makes troubleshooting urls with dollar signs and backslashes simpler.

Comment: @hildred Good suggestion, I changed the answer to use single quotes.

Comment: What does ";" mean in the URL? Is it the same as "&" in other URLs?

Comment: The semicoon can mean anything the receiving side wants it to mean, but in this case, it does look like it's a parameter separator.